# Cómo agregar reglas y restricciones a mi app android con Firebase realtime database

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

Con el fin de crear una concurso de predicciones para los partidos de futbol, he agragado firebase realtime database a mi app, estoy conociendo esta base de datos y veo que es muy diferente a una base de datos en mysql.

Estoy captando a través de una activity algunos datos personales y luego los marcadores para el partido de fútbol.

El problema que tengo es que acepta siempre la información que se envíe, y me gustaría poder restringir, que cuando un usuario haya participado no pueda volver a participar con su mismo número de documento, no tiene opcion de login, lo que hace la app actualmente es que recibe la info una y otra vez.

A continuación muestro los detalles.

En la siguiente activity capto la info a la base de datos.

**PollaMundialista.java**

```
public class PollaMundialista extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText nom,doc,email,phone,a1a2_a1,a1a2_a2;

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

ImageButton enviar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pollamundialista);

    enviar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.enviar1);

    nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom);
    doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doc);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    a1a2_a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a1a2_a1);
    a1a2_a2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a1a2_a2);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference uniagust = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.REFERENCE_1);
    final DatabaseReference polla = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.REFERENCE_2);

    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String dat_1 = nom.getText().toString();
            String dat_2 = doc.getText().toString();
            String dat_3 = email.getText().toString();
            String dat_4 = phone.getText().toString();
            String dat_5 = a1a2_a1.getText().toString();
            String dat_6 = a1a2_a2.getText().toString();

            Polla_uniagust polla_obj = new Polla_uniagust(dat_1,dat_2,dat_3,dat_4,dat_5,dat_6);
            uniagust.child(FirebaseReferences.REFERENCE_2).push().setValue(polla_obj);

            polla.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Polla_uniagust polla_obj = dataSnapshot.getValue(Polla_uniagust.class);
                    //String value1 = dataSnapshot.getNom(String.class);
                    //nom.setText(value1);
                    //Log.i("Nombre", polla_obj.getNom());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

**Polla_uniagust.java**

```
public class Polla_uniagust {
String nom;
String doc;
String email;
String phone;
String a1a2_a1;
String a1a2_a2;

public Polla_uniagust() {

}

public Polla_uniagust(String nom,String doc,String email,String phone,String a1a2_a1,String a1a2_a2) {
    this.nom = nom;
    this.doc = doc;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.a1a2_a1 = a1a2_a1;
    this.a1a2_a2 = a1a2_a2;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getDoc() {
    return doc;
}

public void setDoc(String doc) {
    this.doc = doc;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getA1a2_a1() {
    return a1a2_a1;
}

public void setA1a2_a1(String a1a2_a1) {
    this.a1a2_a1 = a1a2_a1;
}

public String getA1a2_a2() {
    return a1a2_a2;
}

public void setA1a2_a2(String a1a2_a2) {
    this.a1a2_a2 = a1a2_a2;
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reglas de la base de datos:

En este momento permite lectura y escritura sin necesidad de autenticación.

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": true,
   ".write": true
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es simple, solamente atacha un eventListener y usa el metodo exists() para chequear si ya existe datos subidos por ese usuario

te dejo un breve hint

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userNameRef = rootRef.child("uniagust").child("polla");
mAuth = getCurrentUser().getUid();
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(!dataSnapshot.child(uid).exists()) {
            //creas una nueva prediccion
        }else
         {
          //No esta ese usuario registrado
          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
```

Estoy asumiendo que utilizas algun sistema de autenticacion con firebase para obtener UID unicos para tus usuarios.

Lo que hace exists() es chequear si cierto valor en la base de datos esta , si esta puedes manejar lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Gracias Gastón, en este momento no hay inicio de sesión ¿es indispensable?

Comment: No es indispensable , ya que puedes agarrar e iterar por todas las claves y ver si existe un valor en particular , en este caso el documento, solo cambias ese if le sacas child(uid) y solo le dejas que chequee la referencia, y vas a tener que usar un for con getchildren para obtener los hijos , yo añadi eso del uid para que puedas chequear por cada usuario logueado

Comment: He intentado algo asi como esto si lo que deseo validar es la cédula DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("doc");

                if(!dataSnapshot.mDatabase.exists()) {
                    //creas una nueva prediccion
                }else
                {
                    //No esta ese usuario registrado
                }

Comment: exacto, asi se usa exists

Comment: @Gatón Saillén por favor podrías ayudarme en esta pregunta que es muy parecida a esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/170681/34903

Comment: Si y es que allá era mejor resumida y puntual, estoy empezando a mirar esto de firebase, luego empiezo a trabajar un poco con la autenticación con firebase, pero ya antes de hacerlo tengo varias inquietudes, pero me parece interesante lo de la autenticación voy a iniciar a revisarlo.

Comment: cualquier duda nos consultas :)