# Consultar un valor en firebase realtime database

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Quiero consultar si un determinado valor se encuentra en la base de datos. Lo que intento es obtener la referencia de valor a consultar y hacer el recorrido y si encuentra un valor igual me imprima un toast, y cuenta cuantas veces encontró el valor. Aquí no lo está haciendo y creo que es la manera en cómo obtengo la referencia.

Las referencias a la base de datos se encuentran en una clase aparte, para este caso me gustaría consultar en esta clase la referencia al campo documento "doc".

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pollamundialista);

    enviar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.enviar1);
    //Datos personales
    nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom);
    doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doc);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    //Predicciones
    a1a2_a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a1a2_a1);
    a1a2_a2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a1a2_a2);

    final DatabaseReference uniagust = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.REFERENCE_1);
    final DatabaseReference polla = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.REFERENCE_2);

    //Consulta
    //bbdd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseReferences.REFERENCE_2);


    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Consultando una referencia
            Query q=uniagust.orderByChild("doc").equalTo("963258");
            q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int cont=0;
                    for(DataSnapshot datasnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        cont++;
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, "Encontrado "+cont, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if(cont<0){
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, "El valor no se encuentra registrado"+cont, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                            
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });


}
```

La base de datos firebase se muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase de referencias:

```
public class FirebaseReferences {
final public static String REFERENCE_1 = "uniagust";
final public static String REFERENCE_2 = "polla";
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué equivale `REFERENCE_1`?

Comment: En otra clase tengo solo las referencias asi: public class FirebaseReferences {

    final public static String REFERENCE_1 = "uniagust";
    final public static String REFERENCE_2 = "polla";

}

Comment: Lo agregué abajo de la imagen de firebase

Comment: El problema es que `polla` es un child de `uniagust`. Puedes escribir el código así: Obtienes una referencia al root de `Firebase` de este modo: `DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` y luego a `polla` que es hija de `uniagust`, así: `DatabaseReference refDatos = root.child("uniagust/polla")`; Luego: `Query q= refDatos.orderByChild("doc").equalTo("963258");`

Comment: Disculpa podrías agregarlo a una respuesta, como quedaría en mi código, por favor.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias, ese era el problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano tengo una pregunta creo que muy similar, pero busco consultar solo un campo y mostrar dos de ese nodo en un edittext podrías por favor revisarlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172747/34903

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para comparar el valor deberias cambiar primero el nombre del DataSnapshot de tu for por que es distinto al de la referencia, ya que recorre un arreglo y devuelve valores del mismo

```
 Query q=uniagust.orderByChild("doc").equalTo("963258");
            q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int cont=0;
                    String doc = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    for(DataSnapshot snapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        if(snapShot.equals(doc))
                        cont++;
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, "Encontrado "+cont, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if(cont<0){
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, "El valor no se encuentra registrado"+cont, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                            
                    }

                }
```

Tu valor doc es de tipo string en firebase, lo puedes ver por que tiene "" , al principio lo que hago es guardar el valor de la referencia doc en un string, y luego comparo cada valor del snapshot que recorre los nodos con ese string, si son iguales aumento el contador. Uso equals ya que comparamos `Strings`

Comment: Hice el ajuste pero emulo y no me muestra los toast ningúno.

Comment: Muchas gracias a tu respuesta.

Comment: disculpa recien llego a casa, seguramente era error de la referencia, saludos

Comment: Si con tu respuesta y complementé en el comentario arriba de A. Cedano, muchas gracias.

Comment: podrías ayudarme en esta nueva pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172747/34903

Comment: Cómo lo llegaste a solucionar? A mi no me funciona. Gracias.