# Consultar varios campos de un nodo en firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Al hacer una consulta en firebase en un nodo como en este caso el documento, quiero traer dos campos de ese nodo y ponerlos en una variable String, para agregar información a la base de datos no uso login, uso el método push().

al pulsar el boton consultar, se compara el documento con el que se digíta en un edittext, luego recuperaría el valor de los campos **a1a2_a1** y **a1a2_a2**, en este caso recibo el valor nulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El listener que ejecuta la consulta e intento recuperar el valor de los campos: **a1a2_a1** y **a1a2_a2**. obtengo null.

```
consultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String dat_2 = doc.getText().toString();
            //Consultando una referencia
            Query q=refDatos.orderByChild("doc").equalTo(dat_2);
            q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int cont=0;
                    for(DataSnapshot datasnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if(cont==0){
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, "No se encontró información ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if(cont>0){
                        String dato1 = dataSnapshot.child("a1a2_a1").getValue().toString();
                        String dato2 = dataSnapshot.child("a1a2_a2").getValue().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, " Dato: "+dato2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

La clase completa:

```
public class PollaMundialista extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText nom,doc,email,phone,a1a2_a1,a1a2_a2;
ImageButton enviar;
Button consultar;

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference refDatos = root.child("uniagust/polla");
DatabaseReference c1 = root.child("uniagust/polla/doc");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pollamundialista);

    enviar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.enviar1);
    consultar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.consultar);
    //Datos personales
    nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom);
    doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doc);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    //Predicciones
    a1a2_a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a1a2_a1);
    a1a2_a2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a1a2_a2);

    final DatabaseReference uniagust = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.REFERENCE_1);
    final DatabaseReference polla = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.REFERENCE_2);

    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String dat_1 = nom.getText().toString();
            final String dat_2 = doc.getText().toString();
            final String dat_3 = email.getText().toString();
            final String dat_4 = phone.getText().toString();
            final String dat_5 = a1a2_a1.getText().toString();
            final String dat_6 = a1a2_a2.getText().toString();

            //Consultando una referencia
            Query q=refDatos.orderByChild("doc").equalTo(dat_2);
            q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int cont=0;
                    for(DataSnapshot datasnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if(cont==0){
                        Polla_uniagust polla_obj = new Polla_uniagust(dat_1,dat_2,dat_3,dat_4,dat_5,dat_6);
                        uniagust.child(FirebaseReferences.REFERENCE_2).push().setValue(polla_obj);
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, "Se ha enviado su participación ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if(cont>0){
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, "Este documento ya se encuentra registrado, si es un error.... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    });

    consultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String dat_2 = doc.getText().toString();
            //Consultando una referencia
            Query q=refDatos.orderByChild("doc").equalTo(dat_2);
            q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int cont=0;
                    for(DataSnapshot datasnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        cont++;
                    }
                    if(cont==0){
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, "No se encontró información ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if(cont>0){
                        String dato1 = dataSnapshot.child("a1a2_a1").getValue().toString();
                        String dato2 = dataSnapshot.child("a1a2_a2").getValue().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(PollaMundialista.this, " Dato: "+dato2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que te sea de mas utilidad vamos a hacer lo siguiente

Creamos una clase aparte ( un bean ) con los datos a solicitar , notese que lo podes expandir a los datos actuales que tienes en firebase

```
public class Polla {


    private String a1a2_a1;
    private String a1a2_a2;

    public Polla(){

    }

    public Polla(String a1a2_a1, String a1a2_a2) {
        this.a1a2_a1 = a1a2_a1;
        this.a1a2_a2 = a1a2_a2;
    }

    public String getA1a2_a1() {
        return a1a2_a1;
    }

    public void setA1a2_a1(String a1a2_a1) {
        this.a1a2_a1 = a1a2_a1;
    }

    public String getA1a2_a2() {
        return a1a2_a2;
    }

    public void setA1a2_a2(String a1a2_a2) {
        this.a1a2_a2 = a1a2_a2;
    }



}
```

luego solo recorremos cada push key dentro de polla y obtenemos lo que queremos ( lo que definimos en nuestro bean )

en este caso voy a hacer referencia a polla

```
mDatabase.child("uniagust").child("polla").orderByChild("doc").equalTo(dat_2).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for(DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    Polla polla = snapShot.getValue(Polla.class);
    //Obtenemos los valores que queres
     String a1a2_a1 = polla.getA1a2_a1();
     String a1a2_a2 = polla.getA1a2_a2();

      Log.e("Datos: " , "" + a1a2_a1 + "" + a1a2_a2);

       }


  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Donde mDatabase es

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias @Gastón, ya estoy en esto, la clase aparte ya la tengo y tambien una para las referencias, ahora voy a ajustar la parte final.

Comment: Me sirvió y me funcionó perfecto, muchas gracias @Gastón

Comment: genial que te haya servido, saludos