# Recuperar datos desde Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Existe alguna manera de recuperar datos de Firebase desde cualquier ".child()" que se encuentre? Hasta el momento sólo he recuperado datos entregando la dirección del dato en mi código de Android...

Esto es lo que hago actualmente, ejemplo:

```
DatabaseReference zonesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
zonesRef.child("ZONE_1").child("a1").child("a11");
```

Este es otro ejemplo, aquí quiero buscar el dato "usuario1" que se encuentra dentro de todos esos child(). ¿Cómo podría buscarlo sin especificar cada uno de esos child (.child("Empresas " + País).child(Ciudad).child(TipodeEmpresa).child(userUid)), ya que estos child() van cambiando dependiendo de lo que seleccione el usuario.

[image: Aquí quiero buscar el dato "usuario1" sin tener que describir toda la cadena de child() para encontrar el valor]

Mi pregunta es si existe la forma de recuperar el dato de ".child("a11")" sin la necesidad de hacer toda esa cadena, solamente dando la referencia de la Base de Datos.

Espero puedan ayudarme. 
Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: si, pero deberias usar una clase POJO para poder recuperar el dato exacto que quieras, resolvi esta pregunta aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/172747/consultar-varios-campos-de-un-nodo-en-firebase/172778?noredirect=1#comment324446_172778

si deseas que solucione tu problema en especifico solo publica una foto de la estructura de tu base de datos en firebase

Comment: Acabo de ver tu ejemplo y es muy bueno, pero lo qué pasa es que en mi caso cada ".child()" puede variar, ya sea, por el país, ciudad, nombre de usuario, etc. Un ejemplo de esto es ".child("Empresa " + País)" donde país lo recojo de un spinner y genera un child distinto dependiendo del país que se elija. Por eso necesito que el buscador en Firebase reconozca los datos sin necesidad de especificar cada uno de los child()... No sé si se entiende jajajaja

Comment: entonces itera en el nodo maestro y pone getKey, eso te obtiene todos los sub nodos y getvalue te va a obtener de cada key el valor

Comment: @GastónSaillén arriba subí un ejemplo del dato que quiero buscar, el cual es "usuario1", pretendo buscarlo sin tener que escribir cada uno de los child() que se encuentran antes de este dato. Tienes alguna idea de cómo se podría hacer. Saludos amigo y gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacerlo funcionar solo debes hacer una clase POJO para recuperar los datos del usuario

Esta clase se va a llamar `UserPojo` y va a tener lo siguiente

```
public class UserPojo {


    private String Usuario;

    public UserPojo(){

    }

    public UserPojo(String usuario) {
        Usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return Usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        Usuario = usuario;
    }


}
```

y luego obtengo el usuario de cada referencia

```
mDatabase.child("Empresas Chile").child("Puerto Montt").child("Otro tipo de empresas").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    UserPojo usuario = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
    //Obtenemos los valores que queres
     String usuario = usuario.getUsuario();


      Log.e("Nombre de usuario: " , "" + usuario );




  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

donde `mDatabase` es

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

y `uid`

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

si quieres iterar y obtener todos los nombres de usuario dentro de tu nodo "Otro tipo de empresas" solo añades un for

```
 mDatabase.child("Empresas Chile").child("Puerto Montt").child("Otro tipo de empresas").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

        UserPojo usuario = snapshot.getValue(UserPojo.class);
        //Obtenemos los valores que queres
         String usuario = usuario.getUsuario();


          Log.e("Nombre de usuario: " , "" + usuario );


        }

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
```

Recorda que el metodo de arriba es igual si cambias el child, el for va a recorrer todos los elementos debajo del primer child que asignes buscando los valores definidos por la clase pojo, `getChildren()` va a obtener todos los hijos de las keys debajo del nodo principal (child) que elijes

Nota: te recomendaria no usar espacios en los nombres de tus nodos padres , ya que podrias tener problemas para llamarlos dentro del child

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, sabes si existe un método de llamar los datos dentro de "mDatabase.child("Empresas Chile").child("Puerto Montt").child("Otro tipo de empresas").child(uid)" sin tener que nombrar todos esos child()?.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que esos child() van variando, porque dependen de la selección de un spinner, donde puede dar otros resultados, como por ejemplo: mDatabase.child("Empresas Argentina").child("Buenos Aires") y ahí necesitaría hacer muchas referencias distintas, lo que busco es poder llamar a todos los "usuario1" dentro de todas las listas de países que se generen, sin la necesidad de hacer cada lista de child() para cada país distinto. Algo así como sólo nombrar la referencia de la base de datos y la variable que estoy buscando...

Comment: Por ejemplo, nombrar la referencia de la base de datos y la variable "usuario1" y que se busque en todos los child() de todos los países y de toda la base de datos sin necesidad de dar una referencia a cada uno de los países.

Comment: podes usar mDatabase.child("Empresas chile").addValueEventListener... va a buscar en todo el arbol

Comment: con eso deberias podes buscar en toda la base de datos los nombres de usuario

Comment: Aah, genial... Muchas Gracias Gastón! sos un crack!

Comment: Excelente que te haya servido

Comment: Quiero agregar que lo siguiente se declara fuera del OnCrate.
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    DatabaseReference ref;

y se inicializan dentro del OnCreate 

       mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
       String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();